# parametro opcionales para controlador laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Quisiera saber como pasar parámetros opcionales  a un controlador

```
Route::get('/{param?}','controlador@index');
```

de no estar el parámetro que lo remplazase por un string por defecto

```
 class menu extends Controller
{
    public function index($param)
    {
      echo "el parametro es $param"
    }
}
```

tengo que recibír la variable $param ya que también la usare para hacer consultas pero  si en la ruta no esta me lanse un valor por defecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes asignar un valor por defecto cuando lo defines como parámetro de entrada de la función:

```
public function index($param = 'hola')
{
    echo "el parametro es $param";
}
```

Más información en la documentación de PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Comment: pero que estupidez acabo de preguntar u_u

Comment: No es una estupidez, nadie nació "aprendido".