# Missing required parameters for [Route: cart.update] [URI: cart/update/{product}/{quantity}]. (View: \resources\views\store\cart.blade.php)

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, rutas

Esta sección de código me está generando fallas a la hora de entrar a /cart/show/

```
<a href="#" 
class="btn btn-warning btn-update-item"
data-href="{{route('cart.update',$item->slug)}}"
data-id="{{$item->id}}"
>
   <i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>
</a>
```

si elimino esta parte de mi código la pagina carga correctamente

```
data-href="{{route('cart.update',$item->slug)}}"
```

Controlador

```
public function update(Product $product, $quantity)
{
    $cart = \Session::get('cart');
    $cart[$product->slug]->quantity = $quantity;
    \Session::put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('cart.show');
}
```

Rutas definidas

```
route::get('cart/show','CartController@show')->name('cart.show');
route::get('cart/add/{product}','CartController@add')->name('cart.add');
route::get('cart/substract/{product}','CartController@substract')->name('cart.substract');
route::get('cart/trash/','CartController@trash')->name('cart.trash');
route::get('cart/update/{product}/{quantity}','CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
```

**Tengo un archivo js para agregar el {quantity}**

```
$(".btn-update-item").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var href = $(this).data("href");
    var quantity = $("#Product_" + id).val();
    window.location.href = href + "/" + quantity;
});
```

Comment: Gracias bro, me ayudaste un montón ty ty

Comment: Acá la misma recomendación @porloscerrosΨ considera publicar la solución como respuesta ya que sino esta pregunta se sigue acumulando como sin solución por favor

Comment: @BetaM Listo, a veces comento desde el móvil y espero alguna confirmación de que funcione de parte del OP para escribir una respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando defines tu ruta:

```
Route::get('cart/update/{product}/{quantity}','CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
```

Tiene dos parámetros `{product}` y `{quantity}`, ambos requeridos, pero en la vista, tú le estás pasando sólo uno:

```
{{ route('cart.update', $item->slug) }}
```

Entonces, o haces que el segundo parametro sea opcional, o cuando instancias la ruta mediante el helper `route`, pásale algún valor para ese parámetro (si no sabes aún el valor, pásale algún valor hardcodeado y luego lo reemplazas con js).

Puedes ver en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77750/parametro-opcionales-para-controlador-laravel) lo del parámetro opcional. Y en [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321434/capturar-valor-variable-javascript-en-laravel-route/321607#321607) lo de reemplazar un valor temporal con js.

Referencias Documentación Laravel:

Routing [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-parameters).